# What could be causing my previously functioning Ctrl c shortcut to no longer work in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sigint, ctrl

VSC ignores Ctrl c

My VSC ignores Ctrl c, it used to stop the process and send a sigint but it no longer works

this is what my code looks like:

```
import signal
import sys
import time



def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print("You pressed Ctrl+C!")
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    print("Press Ctrl+C")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

And the output is :

```
python test.py
Press Ctrl+C
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

The crtl c is being seen but vsc does nothing with it

Help:About is :

```
Version: 1.78.2 (Universal)
Commit: b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435
Date: 2023-05-10T14:44:45.204Z
Electron: 22.5.2
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 17.7.0
Sandboxed: No
```

Comment: 0) It works fine for me. 1) so it works fine for you in a shell outside of the the VS Code integrated terminal? 2) it looks like the character is at least being received by the terminal and shell, which I _think_ rules out VS Code keybinding and terminal keyboard input issues like with the `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` setting, but check if you've made any modifications just in case.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.

Comment: Hi starball, the terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell setting was not changed and my terminal sees ctrl C but isnt using it has a sigint, I have also posted the HELP: about too. @starball

Answer (score 0):

pause function call was unsecured or something like this that they got rid of it after some version. Use the below for the same result and read the time library.

```py
import signal
import sys
import time


def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print("You pressed Ctrl+C!")
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    print("Press Ctrl+C")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: ctrl C is still not working when I made those changes

Comment: Thats weird. Do you have full code? You are probably using main thread for something else

Comment: I tried it again on freshly installed windows 10 and it worked again. I have at least 7 cores in the system